# change the color sceme for aptana studio 3

Tags: aptana, color-scheme

I'm trying to change the color scheme for `Aptana Studio 3` to the `Monokai Color Sheme` which is the default color scheme for `Sublime Text`.

I googled about it and I found this article :

http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=15713

now I don't know how to add the `XML` file and the other `EPF` file.

I googled about how to add a color scheme to `aptana studio`, and I found the `COL` files.

Answer (score 7):

1. Install Eclipse Market Place on Aptana Studio
2. From Eclipse Market Place install Eclipse Color theme Plugin

You will find out most of the popular themes after installing plugin.(In Aptana Studio -> Window->Preferences->Appearance->Color Theme).
You can also install themes from http://eclipsecolorthemes.org by importing themes.

Comment: Using Aptana Studio 3, how do you install Eclipse Market Place? I've been looking for its url but it seems it comes already with the sold Aptana.

Comment: To install Eclipse market place on Aptana Studio 3. go to the help tab->install new software then click on the availible sources link then add the kelper site. Back on the previous screen you should wait to see the kelper packages loading. Wait for it to finish loading and then find search for marketplace it should be listed under general tools. Then accept and market will be listed under the help tab

Comment: looks like aptana 3 thems overvites thems from Eclipse Color theme Plugin. Eclipse Color theme Plugin changes only background color and all other styles stay the same from Aptana 3 thems

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this does not work in my Aptana 3.4, but it's easier than that and there's no need to install any plugin.

Just:

- Window -> Preferences
- Aptana Studio -> Themes
- Select theme "Monokai"

Answer (score 0):

It may be old, but it seems like all you need is this guide to naming scopes for YOUR OWN EASY-TO-DO COLOR THEME. [link to naming of scopes](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Current+Theme+Scopes)