# Text displayed black-on-black in Aptana Studio

Tags: python, aptana3

I have been recently working with Python on another system running brackets. I have copied the files over to a different system running Aptana Studio 3. the problem I have is that the python code is all displayed in black and I cannot find a means by which to change this display setting.

[image]

Any suggestions? Is it there is an error in my code and therefore it does not display properly or is my Aptana not working correctly?

Comment: I was going to complain that your image was unreadable; then realised that it was the point of the question :-)!

Comment: haha, can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Hello hudsond7, Were you able to solve the issue. This problem still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after hours to play with Aptana I found a third package of themes, the "Preferences > Editor > Code" property can fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change to some other color scheme? That could be a start

[Check out this question to find out how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751183/change-the-color-sceme-for-aptana-studio-3)

Comment: Sorry I'm new around here

Comment: I've become familiar with the colour scheme when using other languages, is a possibility though.

Comment: Same problem for me. Changing themes does not help.